# VSCode integrated terminal will not allow job control for some reason

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code, job-control

I have a problem with my terminal where it shows the following whenever I start a new instance.

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (1502): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

The terminal runs fine but the integrated one in vscode is not allowed to handle job control at all.

This is all on the latest VScode version & I am running MacOSX with bash.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? It never happened before the last 2 updates.

Comment: How about `set -m`?

Comment: Every time I run a new terminal it prompts with this error, so fixing it inside every terminal will not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to roll back my  VS Code version to  1.77.3 to get it to work.

Comment: I will try it once I get home

Comment: Thank you this does seem to work.
I have posted a bug report for Microsoft on Github & this appears to be an issue with the integrated terminal.
As of today there is no fix other than rolling back the version; the VsCode team acknowledged the bug and are currently working on a fix.

Comment: Yes, it is apparently fixed already in the insider's build, and should be in the next release.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181939